# Opentaps Build Missing Java Libraries

Tags: java, ant, jar, terminal, opentaps

I'm having trouble getting Opentaps up and running after `./ant run-install` command I get the following

> ```
> /Opentaps/opentaps-1.5.0/build.xml:510 Java returned: 99
> ```

I may be able to fix this using a possible solution online but am unsure how to implement it through the terminal

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -jar opentaps/opentaps-common/lib/ant/ant-launcher.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -jar opentaps/opentaps-common/lib/ant/ant-launcher.jar install
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -jar opentaps/opentaps-common/lib/ant/ant-launcher.jar run-install
```

I'm new to linux and the terminal any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to reformat it so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit it and provide any additional details in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed after deleting and re-inputting my entityengine.xml configuration information.

Most likely a simple typo that was overlooked and caused this error

So if you face this issue try rechecking your entityengine.xml configuration

Best of Luck

PS. Thank you -Wtower for improving my formatting